# LAMP mysqli and PDO is connected but mysql is not connecting

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, lamp

I have LAMP stack. And I am trying to connect with mysql using `mysql_connect` function. But it is showing error page.

> This page is not working.

I am able to connect with mysqli and PDO function. But I want to connect with mysql with mysql_connect function.

When I am trying to connect. I checked the error log and there is error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect()

Please let me know if you need any information from myside.

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 and apach2.4, PHP 7 and mysql 5.7.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_connect()` function was deprecated from PHP v5.5.

I guess you have some old codebase written in PHP 5.4 or earlier which you want to run.

Either you'll have to install PHP v5.4 or earlier or change all your `mysql` queries to `mysqli`.

Comment: pdo_mysql also not connected.